# How to make content private and only for certain roles to see

Tags: users

I have a content type called **collection** and 2 user roles: **role1** and **role2**. role1 users can create collections. What I want to do is to allow role1 users to indicate whether they want their collection remain private (in which case only logged in users and hence role2 users can see it) or let it remain public, in which case anonymous users can see the content. Each collection is really just a collection of pictures. I am using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple options (and more, I'm sure):

http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess (easier to set up, but more manually intensive for the end user)

or

http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access (a little bit more to set up, but easier on ur end users)

Comment: Great thank you. I started using simple_access, but I'll look at taxonomy_access as you suggest

Answer (score 0):

Update + tips for new readers:

Other modules to consider on Drupal 7:

'**Organic Groups**':
- http://drupal.org/project/og

'**Groups, Community and Co**' (...):
- http://drupal.org/project/gcc

And also '**Taxonomy Access Control Lite**' ('tac_lite') and '**Content Access**' ('content_access')